# Facebook URL problems with hosted Cloud9 IDE

Tags: node.js, everyauth, cloud9-ide

I have been building/testing Facebook authentication (node.js with everyauth) and all was well for several weeks. Then, something happened to the URL C9 provides.

In the IDE when I launch my application, C9 says to connect via http://myproject.c9.io. This is fine, but when I attempted to authenticate in my application to Facebook, everyauth would generate a URL like http://project-live99823498923.rhcloud.com/ and I would get the Facebook "URL not owned by the application" error. I changed my FB settings to this URL and all was fine until a couple of days ago, and now nothing seems to work in the Facebook Login URL, and I get the dreaded "Error 191 URL is not owned by the application".

Anyone overcome this? I'm on the paid c9 plan and have put in a support ticket to no avail. Not sure if this is C9 (seems very unstable recently), Facebook, or some change to everyauth (I haven't touched my authentication code however).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out. Not sure if this was on the Cloud9 or FB side, but I added rhcloud.com to the "App Domains" field on Facebook app setup, and now all is working. Nothing in my code changed, but it seems C9 has made lots of changes recently, so again I'm not sure which side was causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using everyauth, you could specify there your domain:

```
 everyauth.facebook.myHostname("youapp.yourname.c9.io");
```

Hope, this solution will be useful for someone